# Allow cross-domain scripting and access between two domains

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, cross-domain, xss

I have two domains: domain1.com and domain2.com

I want to allow any cross-domain scripting or communication between these two domains. How can I do it so that I do not get any cross-domain errors while using content between these two domains?

Also, want to access pages through iframes and run scripts through iframes between these two domains.

Comment: You can't do any thing in the javascript layer. This is decided between the browser and your servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the browser as a means to communicate, you can enable/use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing). As cross-domain scripting is a browser limitation, you can also implement a server-side communication path, you can communicate between domains via webservices

Comment: I tried Access-Control-Allow-Origin * in .htaccess but still when i try from iframe(domain2.com) "javascript:parent.tb_remove();" I get error as...Domains, protocols and ports must match...